# Having trouble with syscall.Syscall and the WinAPI

Tags: winapi, go

I'm trying to use [VkKeyScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx) from the Window's API, however the program crashes whenever that function is called. I've had no problems with other Window's API functions I've imported and used in this way. Is there something wrong with my syscall.Syscall call?

```
var (
    user32, _ = syscall.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    vkKeyScan, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(user32, "VkKeyScan")
)

func VkKeyScan(char byte) (int16, syscall.Errno) {
    var nargs uintptr = 1
    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(vkKeyScan), nargs, uintptr(char), 0, 0)
    return int16(ret), callErr
}
```

Comment: Is `uintptr(char)` a cast or taking the address?  The function doesn't want a pointer, are you passing it one?

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's a cast, syscall.Syscall takes only arguments as uintptr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VkScanKey` works in C because it’s `#define`d roughly like this:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#   define VkScanKey VkScanKeyW
#else
#   define VkScanKey VkScanKeyA
#endif
```

So `VkScanKey` isn’t the real symbol—`VkScanKeyW` is, and that’s the only form `GetProcAddress` will take it in. If you had been doing proper error handling you might have noticed that `GetProcAddress` was failing rather than `Syscall`, which might have tipped you off to this fact.